# How can I make a new account when I am question banned?

Tags: support, post-ban, multiple-accounts

I have an account on Seasoned Advice, but it has been question banned. I would like to create an additional account so I can continue to ask questions. How can I do this?

Comment: Mind if I ask why you find yourself in need of multiple accounts?

Comment: I have crossed my questions limit in seasoned advice.

Comment: You'll want to be aware of the fact that they have ways of detecting you own multiple accounts, so if you're trying to create another account to circumvent any kind of question/answer ban or possibly boost the rep of each account, this will not end well for you.

Comment: okay then how can I ask questions again on seasoned advice ?

Comment: Read: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I've pinged a seasoned advice mod about this - they'll be responding. If you crossed your limit, its likely due to poor quality and you hit an automatic ban. Reviewing and improving your posts is a better idea than trying to get a second account.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have suggested in the comments, you have bumped up against an automatic block of new questions from your account. Your account has been blocked because of the ten questions you have posted, four have been closed, one has a negative vote count, and eight (including closed questions) have a vote count standing at 0. You have received one upvote. A large number of poorly received questions over a short period of time triggers an automatic question ban **that moderators cannot override.**

Question bans get lifted with the *improvement of questions already asked*.

So, the best way to get a question ban lifted is to edit existing questions to improve them, which will then result in upvotes to those questions, which will then change the numbers which triggered the ban.

See: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

A lot of your questions would be fine if they weren't duplicates of questions already asked, so be sure to use the search function before you ask new questions after the ban is lifted.

Moderators are not privy to the actual numbers or other details that trigger bans, so we can only help to a point. But, you only need one more upvote to speak up in chat. In chat, any of the mods and many of the other users would be happy to help you whip your questions into shape.

---

*You asked about making a new account to circumvent the question ban.*

#### Please do not do that.

Using multiple accounts to do anything the user *couldn't do with their original account only* is specifically against the rules. Both the system and human moderators enforce those rules. Question bans are not meant to be punitive, but suspensions are. Please read the link above and our [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help). Once you have 20 rep on Seasoned Advice, meet us in [The Frying Pan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan) for more help.

**Edit:** You got some help from nameless elves, and your question ban has been lifted. You can also now talk in chat. I recommend running any new questions by users in [The Frying Pan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan) before you post them until you're out of danger of further bans. The Frying Pan (the main chatroom on Cooking.SE) is a very welcoming place, we really will do what we can to help.

Comment: *The Frying Pan is a very welcoming place* ... based on the name alone I wouldn't think so ...  :/

Comment: @rene Huh. I've spent the better part of the past five years in that room, and I've never really seen that before. But you're right!

Comment: Yeah, I think it is one example why new users might get confused and wonder on what kind of weird site they ended up. Not that we need to change the awesome names of our chatrooms but some might need extra context for the occasional passerby. Thanks for the edit.